# Place pseudocode inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithmicx

How can I place pseudocode, that is written by the `algpseudocode` package, inside a `tikz` node? (I don't want to just decorate the code, but use them inside a graph)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, rounded corners] {%    
            \begin{algorithmic}
            \If{$\mathrm{n}=\mathrm{np}$}
                \State Have fun
            \EndIf
            \end{algorithmic}%
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

Lot of errors like:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `algorithmic` environment resists being put inside boxes, but you can put it in a `minipage`.  Since you want the text to fit the natural width of the pseudocode fragment, I've used the `varwidth` package instead of using a `minipage` directly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, rounded corners] {% 
            \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
            \begin{algorithmic}
            \If{$\mathrm{n}=\mathrm{np}$}
                \State Have fun
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}%
        \end{varwidth}
%
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thx! I didn't know about the `varwidth` package. It sounds really useful. Btw: `algpseudocode` is the `algorithmicx` package ;)

Comment: Why there is extra space before if?

Comment: @alper Good question which I can't answer. I suspect it's an `algorithmicx` issue, but a quick investigation couldn't find the source. If it's important to you, I would ask a new question linking to this one and see whether someone else has a solution.